# Check for empty XML file and resolve an error message

Tags: java, xml

I've just started learning how to load XML files and use them to create objects a bit yesterday and so I've run into a few little things that I haven't, through about 15 minutes or so of looking around, been able to figure out so I decided to try asking them here.

DBLoader: https://github.com/Valkryst/Project_02/blob/master/src/main/java/valkryst/item/DBLoader.java#L93

XMLParse:
https://github.com/Valkryst/Project_02/tree/master/src/main/java/valkryst/core/xml

The DBLoader class is where I load all of the variables from the XML file and create either an Armor or a Weapon object depending on a few things. 
The XMLParse class is just to hold a few methods that I've found myself in need of quite often while working with XML files.

Now onto my two questions...

- How can I, with how my code is currently set up in the DBLoader class, do a check to see if there are no elements other than the opening and closing elements which are "body" and "/body"? (Replace the quotation marks with > and <.)

  - How can I resolve the error "[Fatal Error] :1:1 Premature end of file" when loading an empty file? I've already included a try-catch block to skip the current iteration of the for loop after it's caught. (This will probably be fixed if my first question is solved.)

I did have more questions and that but it's around 4:00am here so I'm a bit out-of-it and I'll leave it at the two most important questions I had.

Thanks for any replies.

Edit: Another error just cropped up that I can't seem to figure out in my tired state of mind so I'll just add it to this post just in case anyone sees the problem while helping with my main questions.

When DBLoader is run it always seems to skip "/XML/Items/Armor/Boot.xml" for some reason. I've added a print statement to tell me when a file is successfully loaded but only "/XML/Items/Armor/Sword.xml" ever successfully finishes. They are my two test XML files so only they should successfully load. Sorry if this sounds weird, I'm falling asleep.

Comment: What you seem to want to do is to save and load objects and using XML data structure as your persistent storage. For this there is many better (read: easier to implement) technologies available.
Design your Java objects holding your data first and then either use JAXB or XStream to write them as a XML file or read them from a XML file into an object. With this you can avoid all this parsing code and all problems around that.

Comment: Yes, that's more-or-less what I want to do if I'm understanding you correctly. I just want to be able to store my entire item database and load it into the program when it starts up. I'll take a look at JAXB and XStream a bit later. How would they solve the problems though, wouldn't I still have to parse the files and load them into the program?  Sorry for the block of text, I can't use the enter key without this post being posted for some reason. I did a quick check of XMLStartlet but it seems that it needs to be installed for me to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Mehh, not sure if it's the best way, but it works. This goes into your for loop.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc;

   File f = new File(paths[i]);
   FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
   if (fr.read()==-1){
       //file is empty
   }
   else{

        doc= dBuilder.parse(f);
        int n = rankdoc.getChildNodes().getChildNodes().getLength(); 
        // if n > 0, there's something else besides your root element

   }
   fr.close();
```

Comment: That would normally work as far as I can tell but I can't use it with the way that my program currently works. I'm reading the XML files from within the jar file so if I use File and all of that it'll just give me FileNotFound exceptions.